# Make LinkedList Generic in Swift

Tags: swift

### Consider a Generically constructed `Node` for a `DoublyLinkedList`:

```
public class Node<T> {
    var value: T
    var next: Node<T>?
    weak var previous: Node<T>?
    
    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
}

public class DoublyLinkedList<T> {
    var head: Node<T>?
    private var tail: Node<T>?
    
    public func append(value: T) {
        let newNode = Node(value: value)
        
        if let tailNode = tail {
            newNode.previous = tailNode
            tailNode.next = newNode
        } else {
            head = newNode
        }
        
        tail = newNode
    }
    ....
```

## How do I make the `DoublyLinkedList` even more Generic?

(i.e. I subclassed `Node` so that I could implement some specific behaviors via inheritance). I can't seem to synthesize a `DoublyLinkedList` of my subclass because it is looking for the "Concrete"? type of `Node`

```
class TransactionFilterNode: Node<Search> {
    
    let seedTransactions: [Transaction]
    
    init(search: Search, allTransactions: [Transaction]){
        self.seedTransactions = allTransactions
        super.init(value: search)
    }
```

I can't seem to get this to be inserted or appended to DoublyLinkedList because DoublyLinkedList is looking for a `Node`, not a subclass of `Node`.

**Edit: Solved**

The solution was to pull the call for `Node` into the function call parameter so that I could pass a subclassed version. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your `append` method expects a type `T` (which in your case is `Search`), while you are directly subclassing a `Node`.

So you can

**Option 1**: create `append` that accepts the `Node`, e.g.:

```
    func append(value: T) {
        let newNode = Node(value: value)
        append(newNode: newNode)
    }
    
    func append(newNode: Node<T>) {
        
        if let tailNode = tail {
            newNode.previous = tailNode
            tailNode.next = newNode
        } else {
            head = newNode
        }
        
        tail = newNode
    }
```

So now you can

```
let x = DoublyLinkedList<Search>()
let y = TransactionFilterNode(...)
x.append(newNode: y) // No problem
```

**Option 2**: subclass `Search` instead of subclassing `Node`
I.e. maybe instead of `class TransactionFilterNode: Node<Search>` you meant to say `class TransactionFilter: Search`?

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly! To clarify: my subclass of Node is a valid type to be inserted into the DoublyLinkedList by virtue of Inheritance? Am I understanding at least that point correctly?

Comment: Yes, as long as you specify your list as `DoublyLinkedList<Search>` (i.e. both linked list and node refer to the same type `Search`)

Comment: Thank you! It works. First time working with Generics and I was a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

My doubly linked list is generic over everything because I conceal Node from the user by embedding it.
He simply asks for a BiLinkedList or a BiLinkedList or whatever he wants to list. Only access via subscripts requires his objects to be Equatable. Note that all references to Node are private.
Here are my headers:

```
public struct BiLinkedList<Element> {
   var head: Node<Element>?
   var tail: Node<Element>?
 
   public init(_ array: [Element] = []) {}
   private mutating func copyNodes() {}

   public var peekFirst: Element? { get }
   public var peekLast: Element? { get }

   public mutating func push(_ element: Element)
   public mutating func append(_ element: Element)
   public mutating func pop() -> Element?
   public mutating func removeLast() -> Element?
}
 
extension BiLinkedList {
   class Node<Element> {
      var element: Element
      weak var previous: Node?
      var next: Node?
      init(_ element: Element, previous: Node? = nil, next: Node? = nil)
   }
}

extension BiLinkedList where Element: Equatable {
   private func firstNode(containing value: Element) -> Node<Element>?
   private func lastNode(containing value: Element) -> Node<Element>?
   public mutating func insert(_ element: Element, beside value: Element, before: Bool) -> Bool
 }

 extension BiLinkedList {
   public mutating func removeFirst(_ value: Element) -> Bool
   public mutating func removeLast(_ value: Element) -> Bool
   public mutating func removeAll(_ value: Element)
   public mutating func replaceFirst(_ element: Element, with value: Element) -> Bool
   public mutating func replaceLast(_ element: Element, with value: Element) -> Bool
}

extension BiLinkedList: Collection {
   public struct Index: Comparable {
      var node: Node<Element>?
      public static func == (lhs: Index, rhs: Index) -> Bool {}
      static public func <(lhs: Index, rhs: Index) -> Bool {}
   }
   
   public var startIndex: Index
   public var endIndex: Index
   public func index(after i: Index) -> Index {}
   public subscript(position: Index) -> Element {}
   public subscript(position: Int) -> Element? {}
}

extension BiLinkedList: Sequence {
   public func makeIterator() -> LinkedListIterator {}
   
   public struct LinkedListIterator: IteratorProtocol {
      private var currentNode: Node<Element>?
      fileprivate init(node: Node<Element>?) {}
      public func next() -> Element? {}
   }
}
```